# In Tritium, what does the yield() function do?

Tags: yield, moovweb, tritium

I'm looking at the examples on the Tritium API website, and I don't understand what the yield() function does.

http://tritium.io/simple-mobile/1.0.224#yield()%20Text

Can someone explain these examples?

```
# first example 
@func XMLNode.foo {
  $a = "dog"
  yield()
\  log($a)
 }
# second example 
foo() {
  $a = $a + "cat"
}
@func XMLNode.foo {
  $a = "dog"
  log($a)
  yield()
}
foo() {
  $a = $a + "cat"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `yield()` function allows you to write additional Tritium code inside the scope of a function call.

For example, you can use the `wrap()` function like this:

```
wrap("div") {
  add_class("product")
}
```

In this example, the `wrap()` function surrounds the current node inside a `<div>` tag, and then adds the class "product" to that tag, which results in the following HTML:

```
<div class="product">
  <!-- the node you originally selected is now wrapped inside here -->
</div>
```

The function call to `add_class()` is being performed inside the `wrap()` function's `yield()` block. The `wrap()` [function definition](http://tritium.io/simple-mobile/1.0.224#XMLNode.wrap%28Text%20%25tag%29) looks like this:

```
@func XMLNode.wrap(Text %tag) {
  %parent_node = this()
  insert_at(position("before"), %tag) {
    move(%parent_node, this(), position("top"))
    yield()
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `yield()` call inside the function definition for `wrap()` lets the Tritium code *yield* its execution to the `add_class()` function that I wrote above.

So to use my example again, this section of code:

```
wrap("div") {
  add_class("product")
}
```

Is exactly like writing:

```
%parent_node = this()
insert_at(position("before"), "div") {
  move(%parent_node, this(), position("top"))
  add_class("product")  ## <-- This is where the code inside a yield() block gets added
}
```

Comment: wow, that's a really clear, easy way to explain this concept!

Comment: So the yield function allows other functions to be run in the scope of the original function that was called?

Comment: Hi @gregorygtseng, that is exactly correct. Also, note that different functions will `yield()` at different places in their function scope, but generally the standard library functions are quite straightforward and they will `yield()` like you expect them to. If you are unsure, you can consult the [Tritium API reference](http://tritium.io) for the original function definition.